# Disabling a JQGrid dropdown in an edit dialog form

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, drop-down-menu, edit

Does anyone know how through either javascript or jQuery know how to disable a select (dropdown) control within a jqGrid edit dialog form?

Answer (score 1):

Use [dataInit event](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules&s[]=datainit) and do $(element).attr("disable", "disable") there. To make this happen everytime the form is shown, either set option to re-create form each time it is shown (by default it is created once), or try to set disabled in the [afterShowForm event](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing).