# jqGrid - how to have hidden fields in an edit form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to be able to pass fields into the edit form when a user attempts to edit a row, but I don't want these fields to be editable - I want them to just be hidden so they still get sent to the server.

For instance:

```
colModel :[
    {label: 'Game ID', name: 'game_id', editable:true},
    {label: 'Component ID', name: 'component_id', editable:true},
    {label: 'Table ID', name: 'table_id', editable:true},
],
```

This will pass them to the edit form (because of `editable:true`) but unfortunately they will be editable by the user. I want to hide these fields so the user can't edit them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

Okay, turns out you can define a custom element as an [edittype](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#edittype). For your situation, you'd do the following:

```
colModel :[
    {label: 'Game ID', name: 'game_id', editable:true, edittype:'custom',editoptions:{custom_element:myelem,custom_value:myval}},
    {label: 'Component ID', name: 'component_id', editable:true, edittype:'custom',editoptions:{custom_element:myelem,custom_value:myval} },
    {label: 'Table ID', name: 'table_id', editable:true, edittype:'custom',editoptions:{custom_element:myelem,custom_value:myval}}
]
```

Then you'd define `myelem` and `myval` like so:

```
function myelem(value,options){
   return $('<input type="text" value="'+value+'" disabled="disabled"/>');
}

function myval(elem){
    return elem.val();
}
```

This will construct a disabled text field, and seems less hack-ish than `afterShowForm`.

**ORIGINAL**

If you're using an edit form control (not inline editing), it looks like you have to provide an [afterShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Aform_editing) function (scroll down to the Events section). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910781/disabling-a-jqgrid-dropdown-in-an-edit-dialog-form).

It looks like you want the columns to show up in the view, but not be editable. If you set `editable:true`, then the user can edit the field no matter what. What you'll end up having to do is disable / set the form element to hidden so the user can't change it's value. `afterShowForm` would then look something like:

```
afterShowForm: function(eparams){
    // change the selector appropriately
    $('#jqGrid input[name=game_id]').attr('type','hidden');
   // or $('#jqGrid input[name=game_id]').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

Comment: `editrules` doesn't seem to work, but `afterShowForm` (which is kind of hacky) does.

Comment: Okay, found a less-convoluted way. See the edit. Comes down to using a custom field using `edittype: 'custom'`.

Answer (score 8):

This is now supported within jqGrid via the edithidden attribute:

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'optionValue', key: true, index: 'optionValue', width: 55, editable: true,     hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: false } },
```

Set to false to hide it in the add/edit form.

Comment: Any idea what version this was implemented in?

Answer (score 2):

i think a cleaner way is onclickSubmit event - you can add extra fields to be submitted.

```
var gr = jQuery("#table").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
var row = jQuery("#table").getRowData(gr);

return { Id: row.Id };
```

Answer (score 1):

*If you can trust the end user,* you can simply add the editoptions attribute and set the disabled parameter to **disabled** like this :

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'your_field_name', editable: true, hidden: true, search:false, editoptions: {'disabled':'disabled'}},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
beforeShowForm: function (formid)
{
    $("#tr_name",formid).hide(); 
},
```

Comment: Can you show the entire script. I am having some issues with implementing this. 

//        $("#JQGrid1").jqGrid({
//            
//            beforeShowForm: function (formid) {
//                $("#CREATE_DATE").hide();
//            }
//        });

Is this how it is meant to be implemented?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's info to pass to your edit database functions, you could just pass the additional parameters through the URL

```
editurl:"database_edit.asp?user_id="+user_id
```

Not necessarily a better way - just a different one.

Cheers

Paul

Comment: Sorry this won't work. you cannot pass dynamic values like this(along with url) in jqgrid. You have to use `PostData` feature to pass dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'your_field_name', editable: true, hidden: true, search:false, editoptions: {style:'display:none;'}},
]
```