# in jqgrid, do all fields have to be visible to show up on the edit screen

Tags: jqgrid

i have a jqgrid, and i am using the popup editor to edit the fields for all of the crud functions.

I have no more horiontal space but i want to allow editing of another field but not have it actually show up as a column on the grid.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqGrid - how to have hidden fields in an edit form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368051/jqgrid-how-to-have-hidden-fields-in-an-edit-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368051/jqgrid-how-to-have-hidden-fields-in-an-edit-form)