# jqGrid hide a field

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid, and having trouble with achieving a couple of tasks. Any guidance will be a huge help.

I have a field (CREATE_DATE) whose value needs to be passed in the edit form. To achieve this I have to make it editable, but at the same time I don't want it to display in the edit form. Something similar to this issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368051/jqgrid-how-to-have-hidden-fields-in-an-edit-form) Something like this is what I want to achieve.

```
$('#CREATE_DATE_id]').attr('type', 'hidden');
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some hidden column in the grid and you want to send the value only during the row editing you should include in the definition of the column the following properties:

```
editable: true, hidden: true, hidedlg: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }
```

If you want to display the column in the grid and need to send the data to the server, but you just don't want to display the data in the edit form you can mark the column as `editable: true`, but hide the field inside of `beforeShowForm` callback. You can even implement different behavior in Add and in Edit forms. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405961/315935) for more details.